# Xhr succeeds but doesn't fill table correctly (repost due to closure)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption

My previous question was closed because it said [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) would solve my problem. It didn't.

---

I am making a request to an API hosted locally to decrypt strings, then fill a table with other info.

For some reason, the request returns successfully but only the last row in the field gets filled in with the returned text.

There are no errors anywhere on the server or webpage.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Datastore = require('nedb')
const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./crypto')

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/database', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  var userId = req._passport.session.user
  var dbForUser = new Datastore('./passwords/' + userId + '.db')
  dbForUser.loadDatabase()
  dbForUser.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return res.render('database.ejs', { db: docs })
  })
})

app.get('/database/decrypt', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await decrypt(JSON.parse(req.query.password)))
})
```

**crypto.js**

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';
const secretKey = process.env.CRYPTO_KEY;
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

const encrypt = (text) => {

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);

    const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()]);

    return {
        iv: iv.toString('hex'),
        content: encrypted.toString('hex')
    };
};

const decrypt = (hash) => {

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, Buffer.from(hash.iv, 'hex'));

    const decrpyted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(hash.content, 'hex')), decipher.final()]);

    return decrpyted.toString();
};

module.exports = {
    encrypt,
    decrypt
};
```

**database.ejs (most is omitted)**

```html
<body onload="display();">
    <h1>My Passwords</h1>
    <button onclick="newPassword();">Add Password <strong>+</strong></button><br><br>
    <table style="width:100%" id="table" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Buttons</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      function display() { 
            
        
        // Displaying results timee
        var results = <%-JSON.stringify(db)%>
        if (results.length == 0) {
          alert("No passwords in your database. Please create a new password in the following dalog.")
          newPassword()
        }
          var table = document.getElementById('table')
          function ajax(method, url, done) {
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open(method, url)
              xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
                  done(null, xhr.responseText)
                }
              };
              xhr.onerror = function() {
                done(xhr.responseText)
              };
              xhr.send();
            };
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              var row = table.insertRow(-1);
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  
              ajax('GET', '/database/decrypt?password=' + JSON.stringify(results[i].password), function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                cell4.innerHTML = data + ` <button onclick="copy('`+ data + `')">Copy</button>`
              })
  
              cell1.innerHTML = results[i].code
              cell2.innerHTML = results[i].link + " <a href=" + results[i].link + ">Open</a>"
              cell3.innerHTML = results[i].name + ` <button onclick='copy("` + results[i].name + `")'>Copy</button>`
              cell5.innerHTML = `<button onclick='deleteEntry("` + results[i].code + `")'>Delete</button> <button onclick='edit("` + results[i].code + `")'>Edit</button>`
            
          }
          document.getElementById('load-dots').style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You've just reposed your question without trying to understand why your previous question was closed as duplicate and without trying to understand the canonical answer. Look into your for-loop, what happens in the ajax call and what the value of `i` is. You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: I changed var to let and it still didn't work and `i` is increasing as it should.

Comment: It is not fixed.

Comment: Please edit your original question with what you tried and didn't work. If it is sufficient it will be reopened

Comment: It's fixed. sorry, i used `.forEach()`